# How export full result Databricks Azure

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am exporting data from the databricks manually by the full dowload result option using the command "display"
Example

```
display (predictions.select ("productid", "prediction"))
```

But it only returns 1,000,000, I have many more records. Is there any limitation on DataBricks regarding Export Full Result?

What can I do to download all my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, databricks display only a limited dataframe. It allows you to download the data like a csv, but I guess its also limited. You can save the dataframe as a table in the databricks database with this:

```
predictions.select("productid", "prediction").write.saveAsTable("predictions")
```

Then you can load it with:

```
predictions = spark.table('predictions')
```